# Find the distribution law of difference between 2 variable

Tags: probability

Two shooters shoot each at their target, making one shot independently from each other. The probability of hitting the target for the first shooter is 0.8, for the second - 0.7. Find the distribution law of the random variable X - the difference between the number of hits of the first shooter and the number of hits of the second shooter, find the mathematical expectation M (X), the variance D (X), and also plot the distribution function F (x).
Discrete Random Variable - Theme

From what I understood, this is a geometric law, right ?

So $$\mathrm P(X=x)=P(A-B=x)=P(A=k,B=k-x)=P(A=k)*P(B=k-x)=\sum_{x=1}^{k-1}(0.8(1-0.8)^{x-1}*(0.7(1-0.7)^{k-x-1} $$

$$ M(X)=M(A)-M(B)= \frac{1}{0.8} - \frac{1}{0.7} = -0.17$$

$$ D(X) = D(A) - D(B) = \frac{1-0.8}{0.8^2}-\frac{1-0.7}{0.7^2}=-0.29$$

I didn't know the last one, and this is a just an exercise sent to me by a friend and translated to english 
Can you correct anything I did wrong and solve the last one, please.

For any russian speakers, here is the original exercise

> Два стрелка стреляют каждый по своей мишени, делая независимо друг от друга по одному выстрелу. Вероятность попадания в мишень для первого стрелка 0,8, для второго - 0,7. Найти закон распределения случайной величины X - разности между числом попаданий первого стрелка и числом попаданий второго стрелка, найти математическое ожидание M(X), дисперсию D(X), а также построить график функции распределения F(x).

Comment: How many attempts has each of the shooter taken before which we evaluate $X$? It is straightforward to see that the values $X$ can assume will depend on the number of shots taken. To me $X$ seems to be more of a random walk on the set of integers.

Comment: @sudeep5221 It doesn't say how many attempts we have or the shooters had. For my solution, I assumed the shooters had k number of shots. Maybe, idk ))